# How to figure our child view's state from Fragment

Tags: android

[image][image]Please see the image to understand the question better.

I have a fragment with an ExpandableListView and few buttons.

The ExpandableListView -> has ListViews as each child elements -> each row in ListView is a combination of ImageView, TextView and a checkbox.
The ExpandableListView is populated by a CustomAdapter ( which is a separate java file from the Fragment )

Question is - how do i find out which Child of the ExpandableListView is selected, from the button.

- I could store the information in SharedPreferences, but I might have to use a complex java Collections object. I want to avoid this.
- Fragment and Adapter are two separate files and to my knowledge have no systematic callback.
- What is the standard way of - a Fragment being able to access each of its child view's information ??

Any help or pointers welcome !! Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you create and set the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener call back interface, something like:

```
public interface ListenerChildSelected
{
    public void onChildSelected(int childNum);
}
```

Then, make your Fragment implement this listener:

```
public class FragmentTest implements ListenerChildSelected
```

Then, when you instantiate your custom Adapter, pass in the listener:

```
//kv 3rd parameter would be listener
CustomBaseAdapter customBaseAdapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, items, this);
```

Then, in the constructor of your CustomBaseAdapter, set a member field to the listener:

```
public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items, ListenerChildSelected listenerChildSelected)
{
    mListenerChildSelected = listenerChildSelected;
    ...
}
```

Then, every time an item is checked, call:

```
mListenerChildSelected.onChildSelected(rowNum);
```

Comment: Thanks @Karim ! your solution practically means, calling the Fragment each time we are doing something in the Adapter ( in this case achieved by an interface call ). Is this right ?

Comment: Yes Deep, every time your Checkbox's onCheckedChange() is called, you'd call your ListenerChildSelected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the `ExpandableListView` in `onCreateView()` and store a reference to it.
2. In your button's anonymous `onClick()` handler, call `getSelectedPosition()` on the reference stored in step 1.